# Android Pinch to Zoom ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, pinchzoom

I have a single Image `ImageView` Layout .

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class americanfootball extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.americanfootball);
    }

}
```

How to enable simple pinch to zoom on the image ?

Comment: check this library https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom - the test has how to use src

Answer (score 5):

You have to use a custom ImageView to do that. use something like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;

public class PinchImageView extends View {

private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

private Drawable mImage;
private float mPosX;
private float mPosY;

private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

public PinchImageView(Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);
mImage=act.getResources().getDrawable(context.getResources().getIdentifier("imag­ename", "drawable", "packagename"));

    mImage.setBounds(0, 0, mImage.getIntrinsicWidth(), mImage.getIntrinsicHeight());
}

public PinchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public PinchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;
        mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
        final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
        final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

        // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
        if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
            final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
            final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

            mPosX += dx;
            mPosY += dy;

            invalidate();
        }

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;

        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
        final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
        final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
            // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
            // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
            final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
            mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
        }
        break;
    }
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    Log.d("DEBUG", "X: "+mPosX+" Y: "+mPosY);
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    mImage.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a custom *ImageView* try this open-source library: https://github.com/martinwithaar/PinchToZoom

It doesn't extend the *ImageView* class so you could potentially use other *ImageView* implementations as well. Besides that it has some really sleek animations IMHO.