# Zoom options to programmatically created imageview

Tags: android

I am new to android .I have created image view by programmatically.I want to add pinch zoom options to the image view. how to achieve it please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)  It has more options

Answer (score 1):

[Android imageView Zoom-in and Zoom-Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out)

[Android Pinch to Zoom ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479958/android-pinch-to-zoom-imageview)

[How can I get zoom functionality for images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images)

but i like to use WebView, which has built in zoom controls.

```
private WebView mWebView;
    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", "<img src=\"banner5.png\" height=\"98%\" width=\"100%\"/>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```